# how to quickly compare all elements in an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, html5-canvas

I have a string with 100 elements, and there are 100 objects for that array. These objects have X and y values. I want to find elements that have the same X and y values. How can I do that?

```
 for (var i = 0; i < circleArray.length; ++i) {
                for (var j = 1; j < circleArray.length; ++j)
                    if (circleArray[i].x == circleArray[j].x && circleArray[i].y == circleArray[j].y) {
                        console.log("mission completed");
                    }
            }
```

I do it the way I do it above but it eats a lot of performance and works very slowly.

All codes: https://codepen.io/tolgaand/pen/PoYzaKP

Comment: What is your desired output though? Do you just wish to know if two elements in your array have the same x & y coords? (so a `true`/`false` value to indicate this)

Comment: can you share some sample data

Comment: sumit: Code: https://codepen.io/tolgaand/pen/PoYzaKP
Nick Parsons: Yes, I want to delete objects with the same x and y values.

Comment: @TolgaÇağlayan—put all the information in the original post, not in comments. The linked code does not include sample data or output (which should be in the OP).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a `Set` to see whether a duplicate element is encountered based on the two properties `x` and `y`, if it is a duplicate we add it to the `dup` array:

```js
const circleArray = [{x: 100, y: 200, c: 30}, {x:50, y:40, c:56}, 
                     {x:23, y:78, c:90}, {x:50, y:40, c:78}, 
                     {x:23, y:78, c:98}, {x:2, y:378, c:90}, 
                     {x:237, y:8, c:10}];
                     
//To get the duplicate objects
const seen = new Set();
const dup = circleArray.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  //if size is same, the object is a duplicate based on x and y props
  if(seen.size === seen.add(obj.x + "|" + obj.y).size){ 
    acc.push(obj);
  }
return acc;
}, []);
console.log(dup);
```

To remove duplicates and we can use `Array.prototype.filter` to filter out the duplicate objects into a new array based on `x` & `y` properties :

```js
//To remove duplicates 
const circleArray = [{x: 100, y: 200, c: 30}, {x:50, y:40, c:56}, 
                         {x:23, y:78, c:90}, {x:50, y:40, c:78}, 
                         {x:23, y:78, c:98}, {x:2, y:378, c:90}, 
                         {x:237, y:8, c:10}];
                         
const seen = new Set();
const filtered = circleArray.filter((obj) => {
 //if size is same, the object is a duplicate based on x and y props
 return seen.size !== seen.add(obj.x + "|" + obj.y).size
});
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: This won't work for certain values, particularly those not ending in a `0`.

Comment: @JackBashford Hey Jack, can you give an example please? I'll try to fix the code

Comment: If `x` is `23` and `y` is `78`, how will that tell the difference between `x: 2, y: 378` or `x: 237, y: 8`?

Comment: @JackBashford yes good point, I think a separator will fix it right?

Answer (score 1):

Use `some` - it'll stop as soon as it finds a matching pair:

```
if (circleArray.some(({ x, y }, i) => circleArray.some(({ x: x2, y: y2 }, j) => i != j && x == x2 && y == y2))) {
    console.log("Mission completed!");
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this always be true in that each element is being compared with itself and thus each element will always have a matching pair (at least itself)? You would need to split on the index I would think.

Comment: Like if you try with `[{"x":1,"y":2},{"x":1,"y":3},{"x":1,"y":5}]`, the statement evaluates to true, even though there are no matches.

Comment: Fixed @rb612, any better?

Answer (score 0):

You may exclude the identical items in every iteration so the number of iterations for the next loop decreases. and the worst case would happen when you have no identical objects.

```
            circleArray.splice(j, 1);
```

Full Code

```
for (var i = 0; i < circleArray.length; ++i)
{

    for (var j = 1; j < circleArray.length; ++j)
        if (circleArray[i].x == circleArray[j].x && circleArray[i].y == circleArray[j].y)
        {
            console.log("mission completed")
            circleArray.splice(j, 1);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is to remove both duplicates. If that isn't correct, please clarify the requirement. I don't see how the OP relates to the linked code, the following is based on the code in the OP.

One approach is to create an index of values that references the index of the related object in *circleArray*. When duplicates are found, their indexes are added to a *remove* array. The *remove* array is looped over to remove all duplicates. This will loop over the original array and duplicates array once each.

By inserting the indexes to remove at the equivalent index in the *remove* array, the logic is simplified, the indexes to remove stay in order without sorting and the *remove* array is kept as small as possible, so the final *reduceRight* only iterates as often as required (*reduceRight* only visits elements that exist, e.g. `[,1,,,,5]` will only iterate twice).

```js
let circleArray = [
  {x: 0, y:0},
  {x: 5, y:5},  // dupe
  {x: 1, y:1},
  {x: 2, y:2},  // dupe
  {x: 2, y:2},  // dupe
  {x: 5, y:5},  // dupe
  {x: 3, y:3},  // dupe
  {x: 4, y:4},
  {x: 5, y:5},  // dupe
  {x: 3, y:3},  // dupe
  {x: 6, y:6},
  {x: 5, y:5}   // dupe
];

function removeDupes(arr) {

  // Array of indexes to remove
  let remove = [];

  // Get indexes to remove
  arr.reduce((acc, obj, i) => {

    // Create key from x and y values
    let idx = obj.x + ':' + obj.y;

    // If it's dupe, add it and the initial dupe to the remove array
    if (acc[idx]) {
      remove[i] = i;
      remove[acc[idx].idx] = acc[idx].idx;

    // Otherwise, just add it to the index (don't need dupes in index)
    } else {
      acc[idx] = {idx: i};
    }
    return acc;
  }, Object.create(null));

  // Go backwards over remove and splice dupes
  remove.reduceRight((acc, idx) => circleArray.splice(idx, 1), null);
}

removeDupes(circleArray);

console.log(circleArray)
```

Only testing will tell if this is faster than other approaches, and performance of different approaches may be different in different implementations.

A better approach may be to avoid creating duplicates in the first place, say by having an index of values that is maintained as they're put into the *circeArray* and not inserting duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this using JavaScript array methods .map(), .reduce(), .filter(). and .find(). PFB the sample code.

```
var arrA=[{x:10,y:20},{x:30,y:40},{x:50,y:60}];
var arrB=[{x:12,y:20},{x:21,y:40},{x:51,y:60},{x:50,y:60}];

var result = arrA.map(function (ele, i) {
      var res=arrB.find(function(item, index, array) {
        return (item.x==ele.x && item.y==ele.y) ? (item['j']=index) : null;
      });
      if(res !=null){ res['i']=i;}
      return res;
});
var finalresult= result.filter(item => item !=null);
```

Output: [{"x":50,"y":60,"j":3,"i":2}]